# rails + unicorn + nginx Connection Refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I am getting the following error in my /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2014/07/08 21:55:00 [error] 1564#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.146.124.12, server: localstyling.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "localstyling.com"
```

I have a symlink in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled that links to my nginx.conf in the /var/www/localstyling folder:

```
upstream unicorn{
        server unix:/tmp/unicorn.localstyling.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name localstyling.com;
  root /var/www/localstyling/public;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I have 4 unicorn processes currently running in daemon mode the unicorn.rb file that loaded them is:

```
app_path = "/var/www/localstyling"

worker_processes 4
listen "/tmp/unicorn.localstyling.sock"
timeout 180
preload_app true
working_directory  app_path
pid "#{app_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "log/unicorn.log"

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      puts "No process found, someone did our work for us?"
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I am not sure what the problem is but I am constantly getting 502 response from the server, I have restarted nginx and unicorn after a few small edit attempts but nothing appears to be working.

Comment: Is your server working if you try port 8080 (before nginx)?

Comment: What do the error logs say? /var/log/nginx/error.log?

Comment: Ruby Race, 8080 is closed, not sure what you mean by 'before nginx'

Comment: Iceman, the first section of my question shows the error

Comment: I had exactly the same error but in my case it was due unicorn which was stopped. 
Starting unicorn after having restarted nginx solved my problem.